# Should I use html.encode for queryString to prevent cross site scripting issue in c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have an ITS soap solution and I was wondering if I should use `html.encode` for the query string.

```
[ValidateInput(false)]
public ActionResult Sample()
{
    string testLogin = Request.QueryString["testLogin"];
    if (string.Equals(testLogin, "true"))
    {
        return View("TestLoginView");
    }
}
```

I have given the validateinput as false, does my page becomes more secure if I make it as true?
In place of `Request.QueryString["testLogin"]` should I use `html.encode(Request.QueryString["testLogin"])` to make it more secure?

Comment: "More secure" from what?  What security problem are you looking to solve in this example?

Comment: @David I'm talking about cross site scripting attacks

Comment: @Coding_ninja xss usually involves writing a value back to the browser, to be executed by a client in an unexpected and malicious way; since you're *not doing that here*, xss **does not apply**. That doesn't mean other abuses don't need to be considered, but: xss is not one of them. Likewise, you don't need to worry about SQL injection *because you're not doing SQL*. If that sounds silly, sorry: but - you're not doing anything xss-related with this data.

Comment: @Coding_ninja Your best bet is to [learn what that is](https://owasp.org/www-community/attacks/xss/), not just call random functions and hope for the best.  "Security" doesn't come from calling a function that "makes it more secure", it comes from understanding the threats and when/how/why to apply the solutions.

Answer (score 2):

You should only use `Html.Encode` when *converting non-html data to html*, i.e. encoding it as html. In your example, you're comparing a value against another value - *not* doing anything involving html; so no: you do not need to html-encode it. However, since you're comparing it to the literal `"html"` (which doesn't involve any escaped tokens), it also won't change the truthiness (or not) of that test - it is just unnecessary.

Typically you might use `Html.Encode` when rendering data in an html view, although it is usually easier to use the inbuilt encoding in modern razor.